# MLFlow run passing Google Application credentials

Tags: docker, mlflow

I want to pass my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable when I run `mlflow run` using a Docker container:

This is my current `docker run` when using mlflow run:

```
 Running command 'docker run --rm -e MLFLOW_RUN_ID=f18667e37ecb486cac4631cbaf279903 -e MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://3.1.1.11:5000 -e MLFLOW_EXPERIMENT_ID=0 mlflow_gcp:33156ee python -m trainer.task --job-dir /tmp/ \
    --num-epochs 10 \
    --train-steps 1000 \
    --eval-steps 1 \
    --train-files gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/census/data/adult.data.csv \
    --eval-files gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/census/data/adult.test.csv \
    --batch-size 128
```

This is how I would normally pass it:

```
docker run \
   -p 9090:${PORT} \
   -e PORT=${PORT} \
   -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/[FILE_NAME].json
```

What is the best way to option to pass this value to mlflow? I'm writing files in GCS and Docker requires access to GCP.

MLproject contents

```
name: mlflow_gcp
docker_env:
  image: mlflow-gcp-example
entry_points:
  main:
    parameters:
      job_dir:
        type: string
        default: '/tmp/'
      num_epochs:
        type: int
        default: 10
      train_steps:
        type: int
        default: 1000
      eval_steps:
        type: int
        default: 1
      batch_size:
        type: int
        default: 64
      train_files:
        type: string
        default: 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/census/data/adult.data.csv'
      eval_files:
        type: string
        default: 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/census/data/adult.test.csv'
      mlflow_tracking_uri:
        type: uri
        default: ''

    command: |
        python -m trainer.task --job-dir {job_dir} \
            --num-epochs {num_epochs} \
            --train-steps {train_steps} \
            --eval-steps {eval_steps} \
            --train-files {train_files} \
            --eval-files {eval_files} \
            --batch-size {batch_size} \
            --mlflow-tracking-uri {mlflow_tracking_uri}
```

I already tried in Python file and fails since Docker has no access to local file system:

```
import os
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/user/key.json"
```

Comment: I call container from inside a GCP compute instance and error is gone, but wondering how one can do it from outside GCP.